# What is the difference between FlxTypedButton<T> and FlxButton in Haxe and Haxeflixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I have been coding in haxe and haxeflixel, but when I looked at it's API for buttons I saw there were two different types. http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/ui/FlxButton.html , http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/ui/FlxTypedButton.html 
When I viewed examples online, they declared a button as

```
    var button:FlxButton = new FlxButton(50, 50, "Click here", OnClickButton);
    add(button);
```

but what is the difference between a typedbutton and button?
What does the "typed" prefix even mean?

(Additionally, what is special about the sprite button. http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/ui/FlxSpriteButton.html )

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the documentation and source, this is what I'm getting: `FlxButton` is the simplest to use. It's used the most often because of that. All you need is a string, a position, and a callback. It requires the least amount of typing.

`FlxTypedButton` is actually the parent class of `FlxButton`. It has a lot of the functions that exist in `FlxButton`, but it also has a [type parameter](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameters.html):

```
class FlxTypedButton<T:FlxSprite> extends FlxSprite implements IFlxInput
{
    /**
     * The label that appears on the button. Can be any `FlxSprite`.
     */
     public var label(default, set):T;

     // The rest of the class...
}
```

This means that `FlxTypedButton`'s label can have a label that is any type, [constrained](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameter-constraints.html) to objects/classes that inherit from `FlxSprite`. In the case of `FlxButton`, that is a `FlxText` object.

`FlxSpriteButton` is pretty much the same as `FlxButton`, but instead of `FlxText` it is bound to `FlxSprite`'s. The only unique thing it really brings to the table is the `createTextLabel` function. I don't know why it's a separate class though.